# Finitely generated module is annihilated by some element in multiplicative set

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> Suppose that $S$ is a multiplicative set in a commutative ring with unity $R$ and that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Show that $S^{-1}M = 0$ if and only if $sM = 0$ for some $s \in S$.

I know that finitely generated means that there is $\{ m_{1}, m_{2}, \ldots, m_{k} \} \subset M$ such that $(m_{1}, m_{2}, \ldots, m_{k}) = M$, i.e. each $m \in M$ is of form $m = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} r_{i}m_{i}$ for $r_{i} \in R$.

$(\implies)$ Suppose $S^{-1}M = 0$. Then, each $x \in S^{-1}M$ is zero, i.e. $x = \frac{m}{s} = 0$. But then $\frac{m}{s} = 0 = \frac{0}{1} \iff mu = 0$ for some $u \in S$. This means that $u \sum_{i = 1}^{k} r_{i}m_{i} = 0$. **Stuck here.**

$(\impliedby)$ Suppose now that $sM = 0$ for some $s \in S$. Then, each $x = sm$ is $0$, i.e. $sm = 0$. Hence, $s \cdot 1 \cdot m = s \cdot t \cdot 0 \iff 0 = \frac{m}{t} \in S^{-1}M$. Thus, $S^{-1}M = 0$.

The issue is that I never actually used the finitely generated condition.

**EDIT:** For rings of fractions I know that $S^{-1}R = 0 \iff 0 \in S$. Does this also hold for modules? If so, then the $(\implies)$ part can be done by $S^{-1}M = 0 \implies 0 \in S \implies 0 \cdot m = 0$ for all $m \in M \implies 0M = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a $u$-value $u_i$ for each $m_i$ (i.e. $u_im_i=0$), so $s=\prod u_i$ sends each $m_i$ to 0, and so $s$ also sends finite $R$-linear combinations of the $m_i$ (i.e., $M$-elements) to 0.

Comment: Is this a proposition for finitely generated modules?

Comment: Which part are you asking about? The construction of $u_i$ is done by your argument in $(\implies)$, and $M$ is finitely-generated, so by that definition all elements of $M$ are of the form $\sum r_im_i$, and multiplying by $s$ annihilates each generator $m_i$ as $s$ is divisible by $u_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: I am asking about the construction of $u_{i}$. How do you know that there is a $u_{i}$ for each $m_{i}$ such that $u_{i} m_{i} = 0$? Because in my construction in $(\implies)$ I received a $u$ for an $m$. Or do you just repeat the process for the generators $m_{i}$?

Comment: Yes, it's just the exact argument that you give for arbitrary $m$, taken for each of the (finitely-many) $m_i$.

Comment: I see. But in order to apply this argument to $m_{i}$, we must have that $\frac{m_{i}}{s_{i}} \in S^{-1}M$. Is this guaranteed by the equivalence relation $\sim$ in how we define $S^{-1}M$?

Comment: Yes, all pairs $(m,s)\in M\times S$ correspond to some fraction in $S^{-1}M$, just possibly non-uniquely